# Django - cannot import name path

Tags: python, django

So i'm starting to use Django but i had some problems trying to run my server.
I have two versions of python installed. So in my mysite package i tried to run `python manage.py runserver` but i got this error:

```
   Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x058E1430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\django-proj\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Is it because i have two versions installed?

Comment: path is specific for Django 2.0, which version of Django you are using?

Comment: Django 2.0 supports Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6, so i guess you should try `python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: Is there a way to see my Django version with pip?

Comment: `pip show Django`.

Also problem could be if your Django version  < 2.0 because `from django.urls import path` is new feature starting from Django 2.0.

Comment: My django version is 2.0.1!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what django version you are currently using but if you are working with Django 2.0 then python2 wouldn't work ( Cause Django2.0 support only Python 3.4+)

So in your case if you are in Django2.0 (assuming you already have installed latest version of python in your machine) then you should run following command.

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Or install python3 instead of python2 in your virtual environment. Then hopefully your command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

will work perfectly.

Comment: he's using python 2.7

Comment: Tried again but it seems not to work both on py 2.7 and py 3.6

Comment: @Gerard22 would u please show me the requirements.txt (I mean pip freeze) file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upgrade django with pip or pip3?

```
pip install --upgrade django --user
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to upgrade Django**

```
pip install --upgrade django
pip3 install --upgrade django
```